# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PHP Help

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to write a PHP function. It is very simple. It is just a prepared statement that queries the database, but I can not get this to work. I keep recieving the error Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object. here is the code:

```
$DBH = new mysqli("host", "test", "123456", "dbname");
function selectInfo($limit, $offset){
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limit, $offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
selectInfo();
```

Any time I call the function i get that error. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's a scoping error.  You're making `$DBH` a global variable.  So when you enter the function, the global variable is not available.  You have 5 real options.

**1. Use the global keyword**

```
function doSomething() {
    global $DBH;
    //...
```

This is not a good idea, since it makes maintenance and testing a PITA.  Imagine trying to debug that function call.  You now need to go find out where `$DBH` is defined to try to figure out what's going on...

**2. Make `$DBH` a parameter to the function**

```
function doSomething(MySQLi $DBH) {
```

It has the advantage of being explicit.  But it's still not great since the calling code then needs to keep track of the global variable.

**3. Create a function to "get" the `$DBH` object**

```
function getDBH() {
    static $DBH = null;
    if (is_null($DBH)) {
        $DBH = new mysqli(...);
    }
    return $DBH;
}

function doSomething() {
    $DBH = getDBH();
}
```

This has the advantage of getting around the global variable problem completely.  But it's also hard to have multiple connections or re-use any of the code for other connections.

**4. Create a class to wrap database access**

```
class Database {
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass) {
        $this->DBH = new MySQli($host, $user, $pass);
    }
    public function doSOmething() {
        $this->DBH->foo();
    }
}
```

This encapsulates everything for you.  All database access will go through a single class, so you don't need to worry about global variable access or anything else.

**5.  Use a pre-built class/framework**

This is the best option, since you don't need to worry about doing it yourself.

Database Access Classes:

- [A quick google search to get you started](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+database+access+class)
- [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) - A complete database access library with full ORM (Object Mapping)
- [ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) - A database agnostic database access library
- [Pear MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) - Another database access library

Full Frameworks:

- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [Lithium Framework](http://rad-dev.org/lithium)
- [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- (really there are a lot more, I'm not going to bother listing any more since that's another question all together...)

Really, the choices are endless.  Find something you like, and stick with it.  It really will make your life easier...

Comment: it did't worked for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080426/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-in-but-value

Comment: Can be move the global option at least down the list, and emphasize the parameter option as preferred?

Answer (score 6):

`$DBH` is not in scope. You either want to define `$DBH` as global in the function:

```
$DBH = new mysqli("host", "test", "123456", "dbname");
function selectInfo($limit, $offset){
    global $DBH;
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limit, $offset);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

or as ircmaxell pointed out in his excellent answer have a function which returns a static instance of `$DBH`.

Comment: Thanks. How would i make that a global and still keep things secure?  Would i wrap the connection in a function and then assign a variable to it like function connect(){ new myqsli("host", "test", "123456", "dbname")} $DBH = new connect();   (The connection variables are actually hidden in another file.)

Comment: Yeah, I would make some kind of function and grab the connection from there.

Comment: @ircmaxell Done. You are right of course. Making a new connection for every method call is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `global $DBH;` in the function, or add it to the function's parameters.

Answer (score 3):

```
selectInfo($DBH);

function selectInfo($DBH,$limit, $offset){
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limit, $offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's simply. `$DBH` doesn't exist within `selectInfo()` function. Variable defined in global scope won't be visible within function and vice-versa. Read more about [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) on manual pages.

How to solve it? Pass that variable as a argument of the function:

```
$dbh = new MySQLi(...);

function selectInfo(MySQLi $dbh, $limit, $offset) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare(...);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the connection is successful.

```
$DBH = @new mysqli("host", "test", "123456", "dbname");

if ($DBH->connect_errno) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $DBH->connect_errno);
}
```

or

```
$DBH = @mysqli_connect("host", "test", "123456", "dbname");

if (!$DBH ) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making $DBH global is not healthy...
except that you can make your $DBH protected in class and set it to null..
and use it..

Answer (score 0):

```
class PDOconnect extends PDO{
```

protected $con=null;

```
    public function __construct(){
              try {      

                     $this->con= new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); //our new PDO Object

                      $this->con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );                       
                      $this->con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );                     
                      $this->con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                      echo "hi.. you are connected succcessfully...";
                  }
```