# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Tags: php, pdo

I am using pdo and I have set the connection string in a config file such as

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname", 'root', 'pass');
```

I have this query in a class , in a method/function

```
$query = $db->query("select aUsername,aPassword,aOnline,aLastlogin from tbl_admins where aUsername = '$username'");
```

and when I run my site I get that error. is it possible that the $db object is not global?

Comment: Possibly. Hard to tell with any context.

Comment: It is global, or you would receive an unidentified variable error.
It's probably not an instance of PDO, why or how - I can't tell.

Comment: Do you redeclare `$db` after `$db = new PDO(...)` but before `$db->query`?

Comment: @Wesley Not necessarily, if error reporting is set to not show such warnings. It is probably undefined, assuming `NULL`, thus being non-object.

Comment: I would have said that your config file should literally just contain the connection string/parameters ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname", 'root', 'pass') and you should create your PDO object elsewhere (or when needed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PHP Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463441/call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-php-help)

Answer (score 2):

Not a great way of doing this but you should be able to get it working by adding global to your method/function:

```
function get_user($username) {
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("select aUsername,aPassword,aOnline,aLastlogin from tbl_admins where aUsername = '$username'");
    ...
}
```

Working with globals this way you need to be very careful that you don't overwrite the variable at any point.

Answer (score 2):

If you declared/instatiated `$db` in the global scope (or any scope other than the function/method), and tried to use it in a function/method, it will not work. [Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

If your PDO object failed to instantiate or was unset before the method call, you may also recieved this error. Try `var_dump(is_object($db));` and/or `var_dump($db);` to check.

You need to do one of the following:

---

Instantiate the PDO object within the method (probably not practical or best option):

```
function foo () {
  $db = new PDO( ... );
  ...
  $query = $db->query( ... );   
}
```

---

Instantiate the PDO object in the global scope and use the `global` keyword to import it into the method:

```
$db = new PDO( ... );

function foo () {
  global $db;
  $query = $db->query( ... );   
}
```

---

Instantiate the PDO object in the global scope and use the superglobal `$GLOBALS` array to access it.

```
$db = new PDO( ... );

function foo () {
  $query = $GLOBALS['db']->query( ... );   
}
```

---

Instantiate the PDO object in the global scope and pass it as a parameter to your method.

```
$db = new PDO( ... );

function foo ($db) {
  $query = $db->query( ... );   
}

foo($db);
```

---

Instantiate the PDO object in the global scope and pass into your object as a property.

```
$db = new PDO( ... );

class foo {

  public $db;

  public function bar ($db) {
    $query = $this->db->query( ... );   
  }

}

$foo = new foo;
$foo->db = $db;
$foo->bar($db);
```

Comment: wow your right i tried var_dump(is_object($db)); in the function and it showed false but outside the function it showed true. kinda sucks that its like that. wish i could make it global all over. for now ill instantiate in the function like you said until i find a better method.

Comment: @Sarmen Unfortunately PHP provides no method for declaring your own superglobals due to a limitation of the Zend engine, something which has been discussed/lamented all over the internet at length. `$GLOBALS` is the closest you will ever get to a customisable superglobal (you can modify `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc but this is not recommended) but it does make your code messier. Something I sometimes do (true OO programmers look away now) is fetch the data into a property of an object in the constructor from `$GLOBALS` so I don't have to remember to pass the it in as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a good pattern called [Registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html).
And a simple implementation in PHP:

```
abstract class Registry {

    private static $_tools = array();

    public static function set($name, $value) {
        self::$_tools[$name] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return (isset(self::$_tools[$name]) ? self::$_tools[$name] : null);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname", 'root', 'pass');
Registry::set('db', $db);

//In some other part of code
$query = Registry::get('db')->query("select aUsername,aPassword,aOnline,aLastlogin from tbl_admins where aUsername = '$username'");
```

Comment: +1 on the use of a design pattern. However, AFAIK you can't use `abstract final` together in PHP - unless you can in later versions? This triggers a parse error in PHP 5.2. Instead of declaring the class as `abstract` you would need to have a private __construct() method.

Comment: Congratulations, you just have shown how to implement a global variable.