# Why am I receiving a time out error while performing a SQL query with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I am writing a module that downloads product data from our distributor's site and then categorizes it based on settings that I have defined. The category mappings are defined in the following `SQL` table:

[image]

The functions are called from within a `foreach` loop that also downloads the data. I did not receive any errors prior to writing the function that queries the above database and saves the category based on a string value received from our distributor. Here is the line where I call the function:

```
//Get PS category based on mapped values
$PsCategory = getPsCategory($category1);
```

After calling this function, I started getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestaprep1-5-3-1\modules\stlimportmodule\model\database.php on line 7`

The relevant functions are below:

```
function getMappedData(){
include('C:/xampp/htdocs/prestaprep1-5-3-1/modules/stlimportmodule/model/database.php');
$query='SELECT * FROM category_maps';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement -> execute();
$fetchedData = $statement ->fetchAll();
$statement -> closeCursor();

return $fetchedData;
}

function getPsCategory($stlCategory){
$fetchedData = getMappedData();
//    print_r($fetchedData);
foreach ($fetchedData as $mappedSTLvalues) {

    if($stlCategory == $mappedSTLvalues[0]){
        $psCategoryValue = $mappedSTLvalues['ps_category'];
    }else{
        $psCategoryValue = 2;
    }
}
return $psCategoryValue;
}
```

You may notice that I have this divided into two functions, one as a control and one just to do the `SQL` query. Initially, it was all in the same function but I have divided it up to help with troubleshooting. My db file is as follows:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ps_development';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include('database_error.php');
    exit();
}
//DEBUG:    echo "database.php is referenced"
```

Line 7 is here:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

As best as I can tell, it appears that I am entering an infinite loop somewhere in my code. No other functions have any errors when using this db file and I can't see any errors in my query syntax. The db isn't too large since it only contains 9 records.

If anyone can point something out that I have missed, I would appreciate it.

---

When I do a print_r, I get the following output:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [stl_category] => Christian Living [0] => Christian Living [ps_category] => 38 [1] => 38 [id] => 3 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [stl_category] => Inspirational Motivation [0] => Inspirational Motivation [ps_category] => 230 [1] => 230 [id] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [stl_category] => Love and Marriage [0] => Love and Marriage [ps_category] => 231 [1] => 231 [id] => 5 [2] => 5 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [stl_category] => Christian Living [0] => Christian Living [ps_category] => 38 [1] => 38 [id] => 3 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [stl_category] => Inspirational Motivation [0] => Inspirational Motivation [ps_category] => 230 [1] => 230 [id] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [stl_category] => Love and Marriage [0] => Love and Marriage [ps_category] => 231 [1] => 231 [id] => 5 [2] => 5 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [stl_category] => Christian Living [0] => Christian Living [ps_category] => 38 [1] => 38 [id] => 3 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [stl_category] => Inspirational Motivation [0] => Inspirational Motivation [ps_category] => 230 [1] => 230 [id] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [stl_category] => Love and Marriage [0] => Love and Marriage [ps_category] => 231 [1] => 231 [id] => 5 [2] => 5 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [stl_category] => Christian Living [0] => Christian Living [ps_category] => 38 [1] => 38 [id] => 3 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [stl_category] => Inspirational Motivation [0] => Inspirational Motivation [ps_category] => 230 [1] => 230 [id] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [stl_category] => Love and Marriage [0] => Love and Marriage [ps_category] => 231 [1] => 231 [id] => 5 [2] => 5 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [stl_category] => Christian Living [0] => Christian Living [ps_category] => 38 [1] => 38 [id] => 3 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [stl_category] => Inspirational Motivation [0] => Inspirational Motivation [ps_category] => 230 [1] => 230 [id] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [stl_category] => Love and Marriage [0] => Love and Marriage [ps_category] => 231 [1] => 231 [id] => 5 [2] => 5 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [stl_category] => Christian Living [0] => Christian Living [ps_category] => 38 [1] => 38 [id] => 3 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [stl_category] => Inspirational Motivation [0] => Inspirational Motivation [ps_category] => 230 [1] => 230 [id] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [stl_category] => Love and Marriage [0] => Love and Marriage [ps_category] => 231 [1] => 231 [id] => 5 [2] => 5 ) )
```

Comment: Your include statement will fail when you put the site online. You should always use relative paths, and not absolutes.

Comment: This error "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" means your PHP script is taking too much time to execute. Does it always hit the error at the same line or does it change? Your using PHP Data objects right?

Comment: @meewoK It always hits the error at line 7.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija Thanks for your input. I understand that but due to my development environment absolute paths are necessary. I plan to change them before the module is finalized.

Comment: @taseaford Seems to me (if your using PHP Data Objects) that there's an issue with the connection to the database. It gets stuck right on the line where it tries to create the PDO $db object. Your using OCBD? This is on your own local laptop?

Comment: are you using pdo inside prestashop becouse you need to access a database that is different from the prestashop one? becouse else just use the Db factory embedded in prestashop: premade statement, singleton and query caching make it fast and secure.

Comment: @meewoK I am using PDO. The unusual thing is that I'm using this same connection throughout my application without error. New products are saved to the database. In addition, if I do a `print_r` then my array does contain data. If there were an error in the PDO, would it contain anything?

Comment: @taseaford What do you mean about using the same connection? Also, are you using two different databases? One from prestashop and another? Did this work in the beginning and stop working in the end? Do you close the connections after using them?

Comment: @meewoK Other functions within the application are using this file to connect to the db. No, I'm only using one database. The data defined here is in a separate table than the rest of prestashop's data. This app worked without error until I wrote this function.

Comment: How many times do you call getMappedData() within the same Script? It seems to me you may be making many PDO objects if you call getMappedData() multiple times. Can you move your include to the DB file outside of the function? Usually it's good to only create one DB connection and not multiple ones.

Comment: I only explicitly call the function once. But it is within a `foreach` loop that causes it to be performed once per product. For some reason if I don't include the database file within each function that needs it, it will not connect. I have moved that statement out of the function to the beginning of the script, but just get this error:`Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

Comment: @taseaford You need to make $db be global in order for it to be accessible within the function. I'd guess you move `include('C:/xampp/htdocs/prestaprep1-5-3-1/modules/stlimportmodule/model/database.php');` to the top of the page, and put `global $db;` inside your `getMappedData()` so that there is a gloval reference to $db pdo object. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463441/call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-php-help

Comment: @meewoK Thanks for your help! That seems to have done it. I appreciate your help!

Comment: it doesn't have to be global, you can include it as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be it is taking too long to connect to your database.
Has this worked before?

You could try the following to extend the amount of time your script can run:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes
```

It seems to be though that it is taking way too long to connect.
Your using ODBC, correct?

**Update:**

I see your including

```
include('C:/xampp/htdocs/prestaprep1-5-3-1/modules/stlimportmodule/model/database.php');
```

within a function. This means, if you have for loops you may be creating many $db objects and causing the freeze. You need to move the include out of the function, and use a global $db variable.

Comment: Yes, this connection to the database does work in other portions of the same application without error. No, I'm using MySQL

Comment: So, include('C:/xampp/htdocs/prestaprep1-5-3-1/modules/stlimportmodule/model/database.php'); is used in other PHP files that do not get stuck there. Question, do the other files close the connection after? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046614/do-sql-connections-opened-with-pdo-in-php-have-to-be-closed . I'm guessing here but maybe you have too many db connections open.

Comment: This may be a newbie question, but is a new connection opened every time the database.php file is referenced? Is there a way to tell how many connections are opened?

Comment: @taseaford, yes, if your calling that function multiple times and calling that include as well you may be just creating WAY too many connections until no more can be made. Try making a a $counter, and caling echo "counter=".$counter; $counter++; right before you call getPsCategory and print out how many counts there are. How many times do you call getPsCategory() within the same script? I see getPsCategory() calls -> getMappedData() .

Comment: I only call `getPsCategory()` once. The module accepts a csv file of ISBN numbers which it then uses to get product data using our distributor's API. My test file contains 6 ISBN numbers. `getPsCategory()` is called once for each of the ISBN numbers.