# prepare function used wrong?

Tags: php, function

anyone knows why i get this error:

```
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

for this code-snippet:

```
public function check_availability($dataID) {

    $query = "SELECT dump FROM dumps WHERE dump = '".$dataID."'";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

especially for this line:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
```

the variable $mysqli cant be wrong because of:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($config['sql_hostname'], $config['sql_username'], $config['sql_password'], $config['sql_database']);
```

UPDATE:

i am calling this script in browser:

```
define('SECURE', true);

include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

require 'AvailabilityChecker.php';

$config = array('DB' => $mysqli,
                'Table' => 'dumps',
                'Row' => 'dump',
                'Output' => true,
                'Format' => 'JSON');

$availabilityChecker = new AvailabilityChecker($config);

if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($_POST['dataID'])) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "not ok";
}
```

$mysqli is defined in "connect_to_mysql.php" so?

Comment: Apparently the `$mysqli` is *wrong*.

Comment: Where do you define `$mysqli` in [the scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463441/call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-php-help

Comment: i updated. can u take a look?

Comment: No you have a look at one of the many many duplicates @user2999787

Answer (score 0):

you should create an `Object` of `mysqli` and check the result

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
if(!$mysqli)
{
   die("can not access the db");
}
```

then you can use the function

```
$mysqli->prepare($query)
```

Comment: ehm i created an object already, dont u see?

Comment: before using $mysqli you should check it by using if($mysqli){}