# Login submit php not working

Tags: php, database, forms, authentication

I've written a .php page for submitting a log in form. It scans the database to check any matches, however, i stopped working on my website about 2 weeks ago and i've come to work on it again, however it's now decided to stop working? I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsubmit.php on line 16
```

Here's my PHP for the loginsubmit

```
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'loginform.php';
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    global $db;
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Users WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$pass). "'";
    $query = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, DateofBirth, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", firstname, $lastname, $email, $dob, $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row["cnt"] > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";

        header('Location: homepage.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: loginform.php');

    }
}
```

Comment: $db (your global) isn't an object =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PHP Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463441/call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-php-help)

Comment: $db object isn't create yet. That is the reason for this error. from where did u declare the $db object ?

Comment: Initially I didn't have global $db; there but that got rid of one error, I don't get how this can work but then not! I'm new to HTML and PHP so little errors like this hurt my head

Comment: Show us the code where you define `$db`

Comment: Don't use `&&` in SQL conditions but `AND`. Sometimes prepare fails if sql contains a syntax error

Comment: Since it stopped working overnight, might be related to changes to your database and not to your code. You could get this error because of a connection error. Did you happen to move your db, change ip, change login/pwd of your db?

Comment: that's the only place where I've got $db

Comment: I put my code onto my computer from my laptop and I'm using XAMPP and I created a database with the same name and table with the same name and attributes, I went to check on my laptop if it would still work there as I've not changed anything on that but nope, doesnt work :/

Comment: You're trying to do a multi query, that's why it's failing.

Comment: My registration submit form works perfectly too, so can't see it being a database issue?

Comment: $db only appears in this form

Comment: Your'e using two different type of connections, $dbo (PDO object) and $connection(a handle from mysqli_connect()). Also, the first query is never executed. I will look like all is well because the mysqli_query() function is executing successfully. You should really just choose one and stick to it. This looks quite messy

Comment: @ksealey I'd say that's worthy of an answer. I'd be glad to upvote.

Comment: @ksealey You're  welcome. However, what I meant by my comment was, for you to put in an answer below, since it does address what the OP is doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Your'e using two different type of connections, $dbo (PDO object) and $connection(a handle from mysqli_connect()). Also, the first query is never executed. I will look like all is well because the mysqli_query() function is executing successfully. You should really just choose one and stick to it. This looks quite messy"

To continue, I would assume that your connection.php file contains your mysqli_connect() so I'll take that route. You would want to remove that global variable and any references to the statement and PDO objects, clean up the values you will be inserting and set them in your query string, replacing the '?'s.

Comment: That you are sir, that you are. haha.